# throwing build Future Builder<dynamic>(dirty, state: _Future Builder State<dynamic>)Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'

Tags: flutter, dart

throwing build Future Builder(dirty, state: _Future Builder State)Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'

Code:

```
  Widget _build Employees() {
    return Future Builder(
        future: get Emp data(),
        builder: (context, Async Snapshot snapshot) {
          print(snapshot);
          Map json Map = json. decode(snapshot. data);
          return Grid View. builder(
              grid Delegate:
                  Sliver Grid Delegate With Fixed Cross Axis Count(cross Axis Count: 2),
              item Count: json Map['first Name'],
              item Builder: (Build Context c, int i) {
                if (i.is Odd) return const Divider();
                final index = i ~/ 2;
                return _build Row(employees[index]);

              });
 
        });
  }
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_TypeError was thrown building FutureBuilder<dynamic>(dirty, state: \_FutureBuilderState<dynamic> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68128878/typeerror-was-thrown-building-futurebuilderdynamicdirty-state-futurebuild)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.